# jQuery validation plugin: using custom error messages from xml-file

Tags: jquery, xml, jquery-validate

Hey I tried to outsource my error messages into a xml-File, so changing them or adding some new messages for new elements gets easier.

My xml-file looks like this:

```
   <messages>
      <element>
        <name>name</name>
        <pflicht>Text bei Pflicht.</pflicht>
        <format>email</format>
        <formattext>Text bei falschem Format</formattext>
      </element>
      <element>
        <name>postleitzahl</name>
        <pflicht>Required</pflicht>
        <format>plz</format>
        <formattext>Bitte Postleitzahl angeben.</formattext>
      </element>
   </messages>
```

And the resulting function should be written for each element-tag and look like this:
For example:

```
  jQuery(".validation").rules("add",{
        messages:{
            name :{
                required: "Text bei Pflicht",
                email: "Text bei falschem Format"
            }
            postleitzahl:{
                required: "Required.",
                plz: "Bitte Postleitzahl angeben."
            }
  });
```

How can I achieve that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myXML;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "message.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            alert($(xml).find('element'));
            }
        });

    var nm = returnValue("name");
    var frm = returnValue("format");
    jQuery(".validation").rules("add",{
        messages:{
           nm:{
               required: returnValue("pflicht"),
               frm : returnValue("formattext")
            }
        }
    })

    function returnValue(_tag){
       return myXML.find(_tag).text();
    }
```

Comment: I don't only want to read the message texts from the xml-file but also the name and the format.

Comment: I don't get it to work. Firebug says: missing : after property id
 returnValue("name"):{

Comment: Found another solution. The assignation on the left side of the colon doesn't work.  I had to assign the rules for each textfield separately. Then I have the name to add the rules and for the format I solved the problem with a switch case. But your answer got me in the right direction. Thanks a lot.