# How do i get the contents of a certain title in xml with javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml

I have set a variable in my url wich i get in my next page, this variable is the title of an article in my xml. I have tried to get the rest of the contents in this article and misserably failed... The layout of the xml is.

```
    <title>
      <artist>
      Nirvana
      </artist>
      <description>
      Nirvana in concert
      </description>
      <date>
      18/05/1987
      </date>
   </title>
    <title>
    <artist>
    led zeppelin
    </artist>
    <description>
    led in concert
    </description>
    <date>
    18/05/1987
    </date>
    </title>
```

When i search for 18/05/1987 i want do display nirvana and led + description, so the whole content of the corresponding node.

**EDIT** I have tried the code and only seem to get 1 answer... im pretty new so i don't get why i don't get more answers when the check is itterated

```
    xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("data.xml");
var hash = getUrlVars(); 
var date = hash['date'];
var nodeList = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("article");

for (var i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++) {
    var titleNode = nodeList[i];
    if(titleNode.getElementsByTagName("urltext")[i].nodeValue = date){
        document.write("<div style='width:450px;'>")
        document.write("<p>"+titleNode.getElementsByTagName("title")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"</p>");
        document.write("<p>"+titleNode.getElementsByTagName("description")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"</p>");
        document.write("<p>"+titleNode.getElementsByTagName("urltext")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"</p>");
        document.write("</div>")
    }
}
```

Ty in advance

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065197/jquery-validation-plugin-using-custom-error-messages-from-xml-file/9065309

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a little JavaScript function I use to create an XML DOM Document I can work with...

```
function GetXMLDoc(xml) {
    var xmlDoc;
    if (window.DOMParser) {
        var parser = new DOMParser();
        xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xml, "text/xml");
    }
    else // Internet Explorer
    {
        xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        xmlDoc.async = "false";
        xmlDoc.loadXML(xml);
    }

    return xmlDoc;
}
```

You can then use this like so to get the title, for example...

```
var xmlDoc = GetXMLDoc(XML_String_Input);
var title = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].nodeValue;
```

**EDIT**: As you appear to want to perform a search on the XML you can do something like this...

```
var nodeList = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title");
var resultNodes = [];

for (var i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++) {
    var titleNode = nodeList[i];
    if(titleNode.getElementsByTagName("artist")[0].nodeValue == "Nirvana"){
        //match found for artist "Nirvana"
        resultNodes.push(titleNode);
    }
}

//here you will now have a list (`resultNodes`) of "title" nodes that matched the search (i.e. artist == "Nirvana")
//there is enough sample code above for you to be able to process each of the seach results and gets the values for the various other properties like "data" for example
```

[See here for more information on XML DOM function and properties](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_document.asp)

Comment: The problem is not that i cant read the content, i have to get specific content out there (in my case i click on a date in the first page and all stuff in the xml that has thatdate should be shown on the next, so roughly said in sql it would be select * from xml where date=18/05/1987) Problem is i dont have php/sql on my server so i have to use xml as a small dbase

Comment: @ToonVanDooren: Can you provide a more complete example of your xml then? With say 2 titles and a root collection node (edit your question)

Comment: Done... Thank you for telling me i should make my question more clear, i got add so sometimes its hard to explain myself and some ppl just -1 witouth telling why

Comment: @ToonVanDooren: OK, see my edit, hope that helps with your needs

Comment: i seem to have another mistake as i get only 1 result, I'm pretty new to jscript but shouldn't i get all the results with that date as it is itterated?

Comment: @ToonVanDooren: Dont use `i` the second time. Should be: `titleNode.getElementsByTagName("urltext")[0]` ...and the same with all the other `i` uses (make them 0 except when getting titleNode)

Comment: @ToonVanDooren: Because your for loop (where `i` is defined) is looping through the `nodeList` collection and the `titleNode = nodeList[i]` code is getting the node at each index. So when you are calling `.getElementsByTagName("artist")` on the `nodeTitle` you will only get matching elements for that single `nodeTitle` of which there will only be one (i.e. index 0). Hope that makes sense ;)